# Symfony static/global Logger with doctrine access

Tags: php, symfony, service, doctrine

maybe i try the impossible thing, but i try so archive a logging system where i can log anywhere with something like Logger::info('some info') or plain LogInfo(...).

So no pre-initialisation with new .. or as parameter/injection (have to us it in some functions with "dynamic" count of parameters). I need to use inside a controller/command and outside in smaller custom made classes and functions, called by some way by the controllers/commands but not extending any containers.

for example i use the MessageGenerator Example from the Symfony Docs

```
// srcMessageGenerator.php

namespace App\Library\Util;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;

class MessageGenerator
{
    private $em;
    public function setEM(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $this->em = $em;
        var_dump('a');
    }

    public function getHappyMessage(){
        var_dump($this->em);
        $messages = [
            'You did it! You updated the system! Amazing!',
            'That was one of the coolest updates I\'ve seen all day!',
            'Great work! Keep going!',
        ];
    
        $index = array_rand($messages);
    
        return $messages[$index];
    }
}
```

I already tried to define it as service

```
# config/services.yaml
services:
    App\Library\Util\MessageGenerator:
        arguments: ['@doctrine.orm.entity_manager']
        public: true
```

problem:
i have to inject it to every function i wanna use it - not possible

i tried use it as an static function - services can't be static

i tried to isolate it as static function without beeing a service, but then i don't know how to get the config/package/doctrine settings depending on my env.

i have looked into monolog too, but here is the same problem, i cant use it without declaration outside a controller/command.

anyone have a hint how i can access the default (env based) doctrine connection, or how i can use a service inside/outside a controller/command without declaring it (static like) and giving the entity manager to it.

(a solution to second way would be lovely, so i can "upgrade" to monolog some day using the same solution)

Comment: Why don't you want to use Dependency Injection ? It's the correct way to go, plus it's extremely easy with autowiring and autoconfiguration.
Have you considered injecting your logger service in your classes constructors and saving them in a property ? By the way you get services in methods only in controllers, other classes can get them from the constructor only.

Comment: As several other folks have mentioned, getting comfortable with the Dependency Injection container is the Symfony way of doing things.  It may seem like a pain for people used to singletons and globals but ultimately it pays off.  Having said that, if you check in index.php your will notice that $kernel is a global.  So $kernel->getContainer()->get(MessengerGenerator::class); will work pretty much everywhere.  It can help you during your transition.

Comment: If i could i would love to use dependency injection, the problem is i need it for an conversion of a more or less legacy project to current symfony 5.

The Controller calls severall Classes, that call other classes, and so on, and in everyone the logging class is (maybe) called staticly, and some classes are called by dynamic class/function names with dynamic parameter count. so i have to throw in the entity manager to all classes just for maybe one single logging call where i need to pass the manager to the logging class.

about the $kernel solution, i will take a look into it, thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Injecting Services/Config into a Service](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#injecting-services-config-into-a-service) in Symfony by passing your service to the function in your controller.

**Your service:**

```
class MessageGeneratorService
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $em){
        $this->em = $em;
    }
    public function getHappyMessage(){
    // the job
    }
}
```

**In an other service:**

```
class MyService
{
    private $messageGeneratorService;

    public __construct(MessageGeneratorService $mGService) {
        $this->messageGeneratorService = $mGService
    }

    // You can use this service like you use MessageGeneratorService
    public makeMeHappy() {
        $messageGeneratorService->getHappyMessage();
    }
}
```

**In a controller:**

```
class MyController
{
    /**
     * @Route("/example", name="page_example")
     */
    public index(MessageGeneratorService $mGService) {
        $mGService->getHappyMessage(); // Now, you can use it
        return $this->render('example/index.html.twig');
    }
}
```

Now, you can use an instance of MessageGeneratorService in a controller or in a service:

> The container will automatically know to pass the logger service when
> instantiating the MessageGenerator

Comment: If i understand it wright, i have to pass it to all subclasses that wanna use the MessageGenerator/Service? or can i pass them somehow globally to all function classes that i call in the controller function?
It's the class in class in class with dynamic name`s and parameters thing.
passing it to the controller is no problem but below that it become uncomfortable

Comment: You have to pass MessageGeneratorService by the constructor of services where it calls (See [here](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container)). Each controller will use methods of your MessageGeneratorService into an other service like in the answer.